# How to determine and command throwing a 403 or 404 in Spring SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a Spring Boot 3 application, when an anonymous user wants to access a page, then depending on the endpoint, access should be allowed, or a `403` or a `404` should be returned.

So this is the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain mvcFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize

            .requestMatchers("/", "/error/**").permitAll()            // access
            .requestMatchers("/profile/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER") // 403
            .requestMatchers("/secrets/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER") // 404

        //...
}
```

The goal is to implement a behavior that allows an anonymous user to access the start page. Accessing the profile page shall throw a 403 error. Accessing the secrets-page would be allowed for logged in users, but anonymous users should get a 404 to not reveal that this page exists.

A quick look at the corresponding `Controller`:

```java
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")  // allowed for everybody
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/profile")  // 403 for anonymous auth
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String profile() {
        return "profile";
    }

    @GetMapping("/secrets")  // 404 for anonymous auth
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String secrets() {
        return "secrets";
    }
}
```

#### So my question is:

Is there any way to implement a kind of decision maker, maybe in form of a custom security filter, that can make an appropiate decision based on authentication and requested endpoint? Unfortunetely, there are no tutorials to find about this topic for Spring Boot 3.

Any advice would be extremely helpful, a direction, a blogpost, or a hint if I can even do it with Spring Boot as thought.

Comment: *Accessing the profile page shall throw a 403 error.* That's Spring Security's default. You son't need to do anything. But it is 401 because the user is not authenticated.

Comment: *Accessing the secrets-page would be allowed for logged in users, but anonymous users should get a 404 to not reveal that this page exists.* That is not neccessary, because Spring Securty returns always 403. so the user can't know if the page really exists. But also it is 401 instead of 403.

Comment: So you don't have to do anything. Spring Security's default is handling it in the right way.

Comment: @dur: Thanks for the edit. Yes, I know that 403 is Spring's default, but I want 404 anyway. First, I don't want users to get linked to the login page, and second, for logged-in users a 403 definitely indicates that there are pages they shouldn't know about. I didn't explicitly state this in the question because I wanted to keep it as short as possible, and with a proper solution to my question for anonymous users I think I can manage logged-in users as well.

Comment: To make it a little more specific: 
I am primarily interested in the possibility of whether and how. Which variant I then use I will see. But I would like to master this technique as asked in the question, to expand my Spring Security skillset and thus to increase my options.

Comment: *for logged-in users a 403 definitely indicates that there are pages they shouldn't know about* It depends on how you configure `anyRequest()`. You didn't show it. It is recommended to uese `denyAll`, so you would also get 403 for "not found".

Comment: Anyway, I don't see any Spring Security support for your requirement. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, the last matcher is set to `denyAll` for `anyRequest`, as suggested by Spring Security. Well, that would be a little disappointing if there is no way at all to implement what I want. Spring Boot may not be able to contribute out of the box, but maybe there is some other way?